# How to get current month and last date of month in MMMDD format?

Tags: php

So for March, it'd be MAR31.

What's the best way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `date()` function:

```
<?PHP
 print date('Mt'); 
 //Will give you Mar31
?>
```

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the formatting options:

> M = A short textual representation of a month, three letters
>
> t = Number of days in the given month

Comment: Might want to wrap the `Ft` in quotes

Comment: Actually, it is needed. Using `Ft` without quotes attempts to use an undefined constant, issuing an `E_NOTICE` level error.

Comment: Yes... I apologize.  You are correct.  Sorry for the misspoken words!

Comment: Should also be `Mt` instead of `Ft`.

Comment: Yes Josh,  Going with the wanted results, you are correct.  Thank you and I've changed that as well